# Setting up Nodejs for WebStorm

Tags: webstorm

I've been trying all say to get syntax and autocomplete working in WebStorm. I've installed WebStorm 7 EAP. Right now, I'm trying to get this simple script to highlight properly:
[image]

How do I get WebStorm to accept `app.listen(3000)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best solution which became available in one of the recent EAPs is to download library via *Setting | JavaScript | Libraries | Download*. Select *TypeScript community stubs* there and add *express.js*. TypeScript library file will improve completion and highlighting in pure JavaScript project. Also please see [WEB-8801](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8801).

Comment: I wish I could give you a +50 bounty. You sir, are a star.